# ssh denied (public key), but id_rsa.pub is in authorized keys

Tags: ssh, key, rsa

I have laptop A, laptop B, and server. Laptop A has access to server. I am trying to get laptop B access to server.

I generated `id_rsa.pub` on laptop B. Using laptop A, I put laptop B's id_rsa.pub in the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I copy paste it, because `ssh-copy-id me@server` can't be run on laptop B, as laptop B gets denied due to public key anyway. But when I try to ssh to server on laptop B, I get Permission denied (publickey).

Not really sure what to do about that. If the key is in authorized_keys, what else can be done? I made sure I didn't make an error copy pasting, but that's about all I can think of. It's not usernames as I am remembering to do `ssh server_username@server`. Please note: I do not have either physical access or a sudo password to the server, therefore I cannot change (or even see) `ssh_config` or `sshd_config` on the server. Also I can ssh from the server to laptop B (via laptop A) but not the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

check the permission on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` make sure is not owned by another user and group. To check it, do `ls -ls` and it will give you information should have user and group, which might be the same.

Comment: I assume you mean on the server... the authorized keys file does have a different user than group. But it still works with laptop A, and I am able edit the file. I'm also not sudo so I can't change its owner

Comment: Not on the server.. I am talking about on the laptop B. If you copied it, it was copied as root or another user then on laptop B will have the user añd group for that user that used to copy it and because of it. You will have permission error. You can use chown to change the user and group or the file.. ex. chown user group file